# "Unable to resolve host" error with Google Drive API

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, google-drive-android-api, foreground-service

I am using **Google Drive REST API** to download 1.5 GB backup file using a **foreground service**. I found that after the file is downloaded partially, the following exception is generated by code:

```
Unable to resolve host "www.googleapis.com": No address associated with hostname
```

I am testing my application on **Android 6.0** device. I have set the **targetSdkVersion** to 27.

I have following questions:

1. Is the device **WIFI** automatically tuned off when the device is kept **idle** for sometime? As I am using a **foreground service**, is it possible to have this problem?
2. If no, what can be the other causes for this issue?

I would appreciate any suggestions and thoughts on this topic. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Starting from Android 6.0 (API level 23), App Standby defers background network activity for apps with which the user has not recently interacted. You can read the documentation about [Optimize Doze and App Stanby](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby#restrictions) of Android app.

If a user leaves a device unplugged and stationary for a period of time, with the screen off, the device enters Doze mode. In Doze mode, the system attempts to conserve battery by restricting apps' access to network and CPU-intensive services. Doze mode restricts to perform a Wi-Fi scans.

You can prevent the doze mode or standby mode of Android apps using foreground service by [GcmTaskService](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/gcm/GcmTaskService).